# Cannot write file 'index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file - but it is(?) excluded

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm getting this error:

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

but the file is (it should be?) *excluded* by my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true
  },
  "exclude": ["*.d.ts"],
  "include": ["*.ts", "test/*.ts"]
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a different output directory and exlude the output directory so that input files will not override/conflict within the existing files.
Hope the following config will be helpful for solving the problem.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built"
        // ..... others config
    },
    "exclude": [
      "*.d.ts",
      "./built/" // This is what fixed it!
    ]
}
```